# MQTT paho - no error when failed to publish message

Tags: go, mqtt, paho

I am using the [paho.mqtt.golang](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang) library to connect to a broker and publish message.

It's working fine except that I don't have errors when the publish failed.

The test I'm doing is as follow:

- I start the broker
- I run my code to connect to the broker. After connection the code waits for an input to proceed to publish
- I kill the broker
- I press enter to proceed to publish the message

I would expect an error with the token returned by the publish function `if token.Error() != nil {...}` but I got none.

Here is the code of the publish function:

```
func (handle Handler) Pub(ctx context.Context, topic, payload string, qos int, retained bool) error {
    token := handle.client.Publish(topic, byte(qos), retained, payload)
    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        log := logger.NewLogFromCtx(ctx)
        log.Debug("waiting for transaction to complete...")
        _ = token.Done()
        log.Debug("transaction Done!", zap.Any("token.Error()", token.Error()))
        if token.Error() != nil {
            log.Error("failed to publish MQTT message", zap.Error(token.Error()))
        }
    }(ctx)
    log := logger.NewLogFromCtx(ctx)
    log.Debug("Msg sent !")
    return nil
}
```

And here is the log:

```
Thu 27 May 17:40:25 CEST        INFO    logger/logging.go:32    logger initialized in development mode
[DEBUG][client]   Connect()
[DEBUG][store]    memorystore initialized
[DEBUG][client]   about to write new connect msg
[DEBUG][client]   socket connected to broker
[DEBUG][client]   Using MQTT 3.1.1 protocol
[DEBUG][net]      connect started
[DEBUG][net]      received connack
[DEBUG][client]   startCommsWorkers called
[DEBUG][client]   client is connected/reconnected
[DEBUG][net]      incoming started
[DEBUG][net]      startIncomingComms started
[DEBUG][net]      outgoing started
[DEBUG][net]      startComms started
[DEBUG][client]   startCommsWorkers done
[WARN][store]    memorystore wiped
[DEBUG][client]   exit startClient
Thu 27 May 17:40:25 CEST        INFO    mqtt_/client.go:68      successfully connected to MQTT broker   {"url": "tcp://127.0.0.1:1883", "in": "41.843622ms"}
press enter to publish...
```

At this point I'm connected to the broker, code is waiting for an input; I kill the broker:

```
[ERROR][client]   Connect comms goroutine - error triggered EOF
[DEBUG][client]   internalConnLost called
[DEBUG][client]   stopCommsWorkers called
[DEBUG][router]   matchAndDispatch exiting
[DEBUG][pinger]   keepalive stopped
[DEBUG][client]   startCommsWorkers output redirector finished
[DEBUG][net]      outgoing waiting for an outbound message
[DEBUG][net]      outgoing waiting for an outbound message
[DEBUG][net]      outgoing comms stopping
[DEBUG][net]      startComms closing outError
[DEBUG][client]   incoming comms goroutine done
[DEBUG][client]   stopCommsWorkers waiting for workers
[DEBUG][client]   stopCommsWorkers waiting for comms
[DEBUG][client]   stopCommsWorkers done
[DEBUG][client]   internalConnLost waiting on workers
[DEBUG][client]   internalConnLost workers stopped
[DEBUG][client]   internalConnLost complete
[DEBUG]Connection lost: EOF
[DEBUG][client]   enter reconnect
[DEBUG][client]   about to write new connect msg
[DEBUG][client]   socket connected to broker
[DEBUG][client]   Using MQTT 3.1.1 protocol
[DEBUG][net]      connect started
[ERROR][net]      connect got error EOF
[ERROR][client]   Connecting to tcp://127.0.0.1:1883 CONNACK was not CONN_ACCEPTED, but rather Connection Error
[DEBUG][client]   Reconnect failed, sleeping for 1 seconds: network Error : EOF
```

The connection is indeed lost. I press enter to proceed to publish:

```
[DEBUG][client]   enter Publish
[DEBUG][client]   storing publish message (reconnecting), topic: just/for/test
Thu 27 May 17:40:42 CEST        DEBUG   mqtt_/client.go:84      Msg sent !
Thu 27 May 17:40:42 CEST        DEBUG   mqtt_/client.go:76      waiting for transaction to complete...
Thu 27 May 17:40:42 CEST        DEBUG   mqtt_/client.go:78      transaction Done!       {"token.Error()": null}
```

There is nothing in the token.Error(). How can I check if the publish was successful ?

---

Here is my full code if you need more details.

Connect and publish to the broker:

```
type Handler struct {
    client MQTT.Client
    conf   config.Configuration
}

func InitMQTT() {
    MQTT.DEBUG = lg.New(os.Stdout, "[DEBUG]", 0)
    MQTT.WARN = lg.New(os.Stdout, "[WARN]", 0)
    MQTT.CRITICAL = lg.New(os.Stdout, "[CRIT]", 0)
    MQTT.ERROR = lg.New(os.Stdout, "[ERROR]", 0)
}

func NewClient(ctx context.Context, conf config.Configuration) (Handler, error) {
    start := time.Now()
    log := logger.NewLogFromCtx(ctx)
    brokerUrl := fmt.Sprintf("tcp://%s:%s", conf.GW_MQTT_BROKER_HOST_IP, conf.GW_MQTT_BROKER_PORT)
    hostname, _ := os.Hostname()
    clientId := hostname + strconv.Itoa(time.Now().Second())
    connOpts := MQTT.NewClientOptions()
    connOpts.AddBroker(brokerUrl)
    connOpts.SetClientID(clientId)
    connOpts.SetCleanSession(true)
    handler := Handler{conf: conf}
    handler.client = MQTT.NewClient(connOpts)
    if token := handler.client.Connect(); token.Wait() && token.Error() != nil {
        log.Error("failed to connect to MQTT broker", zap.Error(token.Error()))
        return Handler{}, token.Error()
    }
    log.Info("successfully connected to MQTT broker", zap.String("url", brokerUrl), zap.Duration("in", time.Since(start)))
    return handler, nil
}

func (handle Handler) Pub(ctx context.Context, topic, payload string, qos int, retained bool) error {
    token := handle.client.Publish(topic, byte(qos), retained, payload)
    go func(ctx context.Context) {
        log := logger.NewLogFromCtx(ctx)
        log.Debug("waiting for transaction to complete...")
        _ = token.Done()
        log.Debug("transaction Done!", zap.Any("token.Error", token.Error()))
        if token.Error() != nil {
            log.Error("failed to publish MQTT message", zap.Error(token.Error()))
        }
    }(ctx)
    log := logger.NewLogFromCtx(ctx)
    log.Debug("Msg sent !")
    return nil
}
```

And here is the main:

```
func main() {
    conf := config.GetConfig()
    err := logger.SetupLogging(conf.IS_DEV_ENV)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ctx := context.Background()
    log := logger.NewLogFromCtx(ctx)

    mqtt.InitMQTT()
    mqttClient, _ := mqtt.NewClient(ctx, conf)

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("press enter to publish...")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    mqttClient.Pub(ctx, "just/for/test", "test", 2, false)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang#Token):

```
// Wait will wait indefinitely for the Token to complete, ie the Publish
// to be sent and confirmed receipt from the broker.
Wait() bool
```

```
// Done is provided for use in select statements. Simple use cases may
// use Wait or WaitTimeout.
Done() <-chan struct{}
```

So `_ = token.Done()` really does nothing; the simplest wait to wait is to use `token.Wait()`. If you want to use `token.Done()` you need to wait on the channel returned; e.g. `<- token.Done()`. The reason that `Done()` exists is to make things simpler when you are waiting on more that one event (e.g. waiting for a `context` OR an mqtt operation to complete).

Comment: Thx for your help ! I miss read the doc :/ should have better RTFM !

Comment: If you think the docs can be improved then please do raise an issue or pull request. The docs never get the focus they should and if changing them will help future users avoid this kind of issue then its worthwhile!.